# Socket.io submitting button

Tags: socket.io

Hey guys im learning socket io on their website, i just dont understand one thing about the event. Where do they say that clicking on the button "send" is a submit action ? I mean i dont see a onclick event or something like this. Thanks ! Here are the codes:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>


    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        var socket = io();
        $('form').submit(function(){
          socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
          $('#m').val('');
          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>



var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: when there is a button inside a form it emits a submit event every time u click on it.  and below u have a jquery event handler thats sends a chat message event to the server whenever you click the send button, this is the handler  `$('form').submit(function(){
          socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
          $('#m').val('');
          return false;
        });`

Comment: Thank you very much, so a button in a form is always considered as a submit button ?

Comment: if you have button/s without a type attribute all of them are gonna fire a submit event. if you want buttons that dosent fire a submit event you need to add a type to the button. theres a quick example for you https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/272022/

Answer (score 1):

When the submit event happens the script sends the data with Socket.IO, but not submits the form (`return false;`). But of course you can use onclick event too.

Socket.IO send:

```
socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
```

For example if you have a button with id "testButton":

```
$('#testButton').click(function() {
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when i use this app, the submit function run when i click on the Send button, which is nowhere called as the submit event. Thats why i dont understand why the message appear on the console only when i click on send.